# variable is not recognized when included, pdo and php

Tags: php, function, pdo, include

I have a problem. I am including my database details in my functions.php file. Like this:

db.php:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $dbhost . "; dbname=" . $dbname ."", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

functions.php:

```
include_once 'db.php';

function retrieve($count)
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?";

$sth = $dbc->prepare($query);

$sth->bindValue(1, $count);

$sth->execute();

$resultCount = $sth->rowCount();
}
```

file.php:

```
include 'functions.php';
...
```

When I try to call my functions file in file.php, so I can use the function retrieve, my php_error.log file shows the following:

[Date] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbc in functions.php on line 6

My goal is to create an instance of PDO and use that in all the other pages so I don't have to create an instance over, and over again. I tried to achieve this by creating the $dbc variable and instancing a new PDO connection to it in db.php. Then, I would include it in functions.php so whenever a function is called, the $sth variable will hold the methods used, using $dbc (the instance of the PDO connection).

Does anyone know why am I getting this error, and possibly, could anyone give me some advice on how to parametrize the creation of an instance of PDO and use it/them throughout other pages?

Thank you for your time and help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the database connection to the function where your query is in order for it to work.